# Как правильно перенести строку в этом коде?

Tags: php

Я только начинаю изучать PHP, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно перенести строку в этом коде, чтоб не было слитно?

```
<?php
 
$a = "100"<br>;
$b = "200";
echo $a + $b;
echo $a . $b;

?>
```

Comment: Какую строку? Что именно не должно быть слитно?

Comment: br должно быть в a в кавычках, он как html переносит.

Comment: Поставил <br> в кавычках перенеслось нормально но выдало эту надпись в браузере-
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\testloc\example.php on line 5
300100
200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно перенести на следующую строчку математическое выражение, это можно сделать с помощью `.'<br>'`

```
<?php 
    $a = "100"; 
    $b = "200"; 
    echo $a + $b.'<br>'; 
    echo $a . $b; 
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Иван, помогло!

Comment: Рад помочь, можете отметить, как ответ на ваш вопрос